# Assigning a Delegate to NSOpenPanel in Nested Scope Causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

Consider the following simplified code example. It's presented here in Swift, but the same behavior occurs in objective-c.

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
class MainWindow : NSWindow {
    @IBAction func onClick_openFile(sender : AnyObject?) {
        let path = runOpenPanel(false);
        NSLog(path as String)
    }

    @IBAction func onClick_crashyByeBye(sender : AnyObject?) {
        let path = runOpenPanel(true);
        NSLog(path as String)
    }

    private func runOpenPanel(useCrashyDelegate : Bool) -> NSString {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel.init()
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false

        let safeDelegate = MyOpenPanelDelegate.init() //same scope as openPanel.runModal()--works fine
        if (useCrashyDelegate) {
            let crashyDelegate = MyOpenPanelDelegate.init() //falls out of scope before openPanel.runModal() and crashes
            openPanel.delegate = crashyDelegate
        } else {
            openPanel.delegate = safeDelegate
        }

        if (openPanel.runModal() == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton && openPanel.URLs.count == 1) {
            return openPanel.URLs[0].path!
        }

        return ""
    }
}

class MyOpenPanelDelegate : NSObject, NSOpenSavePanelDelegate { 
    func panel(sender: AnyObject, shouldEnableURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        var isDir : ObjCBool = false
        if (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url.path!, isDirectory: &isDir)) {
            return isDir || (url.path! as NSString).lastPathComponent.lowercaseString == "foo.txt"
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

When the `useCrashyDelegate` argument to `runOpenPanel` is true, `crashyDelegate` is instantiated in a nested scope and falls out of scope before the call to `openPanel.runModal()`. Since the open panel assigns crashyDelegate as its delegate, I would expect `crashyDelegate's` reference count to be incremented. However, the application crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when `useCrashyDelegate` is true. If `useCrashyDelegate` is false, `safeDelegate`, which is instantiated in the same scope as the call to `openPanel.runModal()`, is assigned to the open panel and there is no `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

This is leading me to believe that NSOpen`P`anel is not incrementing its delegate's reference count. Is this the expected behavior, or might this be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is leading me to believe that NSOpenPanel is not incrementing its delegate's reference count. Is this the expected behavior, or might this be a bug?

It is expected. Check the type of the property and you will see it is `assign` (Objective-C) or `unsafe` (Swift), a strong reference is not kept. This is a common design pattern for Cocoa delegates.

HTH